# Displaying user uploaded image in Python Django

Tags: python, django, web

I am creating a website using the Django python framework and am currently stuck on a problem.
I am using function views to display a page called myaccount, and on 'myaccount' i would like all user details to be displayed using context objects, for this page it is 'user'. I also have another model called Profile, which holds the profile picture and date of birth of the user. However when i attempt to display the image which has been uploaded during the account creation into the media folder named '/media/%y/%m/%d/imagename.filextension' i receive an error saying "The 'profilepicture' attribute has no file associated with it." I have been searching vastly for fixes to this issue and have so far found no result which has worked, i have tried to create a property function which gets the url from the image called 'get_absolute_url' by doing user.profile.profilepicture.get_absolute_url but it fails to work and displays the same error. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of a fix for this or a solution.

I also do have pillow installed.

The code to display the image, views.py and urls.py is down below

views.py

```
@login_required
def myaccount(request):
    return render(request, 'account/myaccount.html', {'section': 'myaccount'})
```

urls.py

```
path('', views.myaccount, name='myaccount'),
```

myaccount.html

```
<img src="{{ user.profile.profilepicture.url }}" width="260" height="234"/>
```

Profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank =True, null =True)
    profilepicture = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile for user {self.user.username}'
```

The model for User is from 'django.contrib.auth.models'

To confirm whether it was a problem with the context object I tried to display the users first name which worked as expected.

The account register view

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(
                user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            # Create the user profile
            return render(request,
                          'account/register_done.html',
                          {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,
                  'account/register.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form})
```

If any other code or information is needed please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using ImageField, have you also installed the Pillow library using PIP install Pillow?

Comment: I have installed pillow, although I’m not sure what it actually does

Comment: Pillow is an imaging library that handles the processing of images in Python. Once you've installed Pillow you would import it to your models.py file by using "from PIL import Image". I recommend using that to handle the image files for Django framework in Python. Check out the documentation on it for more details. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Would it be possible to give me a demonstration of this or does the documentation cover it all?

Comment: Had a quick sweep over it and I think it’s not really the solution to my problem, I don’t mean that in a rude way it’s just gathering the url of the file which seems to be the problem every time for me, would it still be useful though for gathering the url?

Comment: Are you able to display the exact error that you are getting with traceback from the browser?

Comment: Unfortunately not in a picture, my rep is too low but to quote the error ‘the profilepicture attribute has no file associated with it’

Answer (score 1):

After some using some common sense I realised that I actually didn’t have a photo uploaded for the profile picture attribute which would explain there being no url for it... Thanks for the help anyway and sorry for wasting time, I’ve also used an if block now to stop the error from being ran if there is no picture associated with the profile.